# How to query the high-resolution performance counter

Tags: java, winapi

Good morning,

i need to obtain the value of the CPUs high-resolution performance counter in order to measure delay between various software applications. In my c(++|#) i use the

BOOL WINAPI QueryPerformanceCounter(
  __out  LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount
);

WinApi call. What is the proper way to obtain the counter from java. I have search jna without success. I know this is a platform specific issue, but maybe there is a quicker way than writing my own jni wrapper?

Best wishes,
 Armin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the native wrapper code

1) File W32Call.java

```
package jmSense.Native; public class W32Call {
public native static long QueryPerformanceCounter( );
public native static int QueryPerformanceCounterInt32( );
```

2) run java h to create the include file

3) Create a dll "My Native Extensions.dll" from

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "jmSense_Native_W32Call.h" 

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_jmSense_Native_W32Call_QueryPerformanceCounter(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{  
    LARGE_INTEGER g_CurentCount; 
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&g_CurentCount); 
    return g_CurentCount.QuadPart; 
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jmSense_Native_W32Call_QueryPerformanceCounterInt32(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{  
     LARGE_INTEGER g_CurentCount; 
     QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&g_CurentCount); 
     return g_CurentCount.LowPart;
}
```

4) Use it like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("My Native Extensions");
System.out.println(W32Call.QueryPerformanceCounter());
```

fine

Comment: Why would you do all that? QueryPerformanceCounter is used by System.nanoTime anyway. Just use System.nanoTime.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)? I think that already uses the performance counters of the machine and there is no need to write a native wrapper.

**Update:** According to [this article on clocks and timers in the jvm](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) in the section "Clocks and Timers on Windows"

> System.nanoTime() is implemented using the QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency API

Comment: Jörn, nanoTime() returns the time, rather than the uncooked performance counter. Since i want to measure delay between different applications i need the performance counter value rather than a transform.

Comment: nanoTime returns counter, not time. Read javadoc.

Comment: @Stas
No, it returns the number of seconds the PC has been running, read the implementation: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/0cd040567d60/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l853

Comment: @Motes "QueryPerformanceCounter" doesn't look like has anything with seconds. And "QueryPerformanceFrequency" which used to define "has_performance_count" has the following on MSDN: "On systems that run Windows XP or later, the function will always succeed and will thus never return zero.", which means that has_performance_count is always true.

Comment: The code returns `jlong time = (jlong)((current/freq) * NANOSECS_PER_SEC);`